# How to hide console window while executing perl.exe?

Tags: nsis

My installer is showing a command prompt window with the process ID while executing perl.exe.

I want to block it from being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Add this awesome snippet at the bottom of your code

```
BEGIN {
    Win32::SetChildShowWindow(0)
        if defined &Win32::SetChildShowWindow; 
}
```

Original source:
http://samdelacruz.blogspot.com/2007/12/hide-console-windows-in-perl.html

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that it is displaying a console window...

You can use the [nsExec](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsExec/nsExec.txt) plugin to hide the console window. If you need more control (stdin etc) you can download ExecDos and/or ExecCmd from the [wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category%3aPlugins)...